# Best way to include data (that will populate IndexedDB) with offline HTML5 app?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I'm building an offline HTML5 app (it will be delivered as a zipped up `.crx` file). It will be installed *and* used entirely offline. At no point will there be internet access.

AFAIK, there is no way to include a pre-populated sqlite DB (and I know you cannot include an indexedDB), so all the data must be included outside a database, but accessible to the javascript code, and then on the first run, put into the database.

What's the best way to do this? (Both from a development/maintenance standpoint as well as actual deployment)

Do I create a database in development and write additional code to spit that out as one of these:

1. JSON objects?
2. Arrays?
3. Actual JavaScript code for inserting into the IndexedDB?
4. CSV files?

How does everyone else handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I use actual js code with data in array of JSON object. Just JSON file is better, but not way to load it. CSV file may also be desirable, since user can easily edit and inspect. It is also quite trivial to convert csv to json objects.

Comment: Thanks. How do you generate the actual js code? do you write it by hand? or do you have a real DB somewhere that you store the data in and write a program to generate the insert code? I'm wondering how to maintain across updates in the best way

Comment: I let user to enter data on Google spreadsheet and then use this script to automatically convert to js file  https://github.com/mbikt/mbinfo-app-script/blob/master/js/gadget/domain/utils-app.js

Comment: thanks for the help! I think I will back it with a database (mysql or MariaDB), but that's a unique idea.

Answer (score 2):

In response to install, create the database and then read in a text file containing the data and insert its contents into the database. Something like the following:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details, prevVersion) {
  var req = indexedDB.open(dbname,dbversion);
  req.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = event.target;
    db.createObjectStore('store1','etc');
  };

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var data = event.target.response;
    for(key in initData) {
      req.result.getObjectStore('store1').put(key, initData[key]);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/initdata.json'), true);
  xhr.type='json';
  xhr.send();
});
```

Comment: this is a good suggestion, but wouldn't it be even faster if instead, pre-crx, I generated the actual install code (e.g. `objStore.put("employee", {"name: "john doe"});`) and inserted that into my crx's JavaScript code? Both involve generating the data before building the crx, but this way is faster at runtime because there's no looping or file reading.

Comment: It would be faster but possibly more tedious to get working and to maintain. I do not know of any other way to pre-populate indexedDB and would recommend avoiding trying to learn how to use chrome's C++ API.